# How to stop react native flatlist from going back to starting item while navigating

Tags: animation, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am building an app by adding few animations to flat list. But I got a problem here when i navigate to detail screen the previous page goes to start item. I want it to stay at the item where user has stopped previously.
This is how my code looks.

> Home.tsx

```
const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList);
return (
      <AnimatedFlatList
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        bounces={false}
        {...{onScroll}}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }
        onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.4}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
        data={photos}
        renderItem={({index, item}) => (
          <AnimatedCard {...{item, index, y, navigation}} />   < --- Here is the animated card
        )}
      />
    );
```

> AnimatedCard.tsx

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('Detail', {
          id: item.id,
        });
      }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[styles.card, {opacity, transform: [{translateY}, {scale}]}]}>
        <Card
          borderRadius="xl"
          variant="elevated"
          style={{width: width - 50, height: height - 250}}>
          <Image style={styles.imageSize} source={{uri: item.src.large}} />
        </Card>
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using navigation.navigate who change the screen. Instead use push to add the screen at the top of your stacks.

```
onPress={() => {
   navigation.push('Detail', {
     id: item.id,
   });
}}
```